# SQL: Searching grand child table for specifc items

Tags: sql

Consider following schema:

```
Customers:
Col      | Type    |
-------------------|
id       | INTEGER |
name     | VARCHAR |

Orders:
Col         | Type    |
----------------------|
id          | INTEGER |
customer_id | INTEGER |
date        | DATE    |

Items
Col         | Type    |
----------------------|
id          | INTEGER |
order_id    | INTEGER |
name        | VARCHAR |
quantity    | INTEGER |
```

And here's the breif run down of the schema:
Customer can have many orders, and an order can have many items
Note: You may argue that the items should refer to some products table with a product_id, but let it be simple as is now.

From my database, I want to ask following question:

For a given customer, list all the items that start with La.

My version of the query goes like this:

SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'La%'

This would return ALL the items that Begin with La for ALL the customers. What I want is that I get all the items for a SPECIFIC customer with say id 1. How do I write such a query? My second version that would do is like this:

SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE 'La%' AND order_id in (SELECT id FROM orders WHERE customer_id=1);

But is their any other efficient/elegant or a more better way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elegant way to do this is called a join.

```
SELECT
  c.id            customer_id,
  c.name          customer_name,
  i.id            item_id,
  i.name          item_name,
  COUNT(i.id)     order_count,
  SUM(i.quantity) items_ordered
FROM
  customers c
  INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id
  INNER JOIN items  i ON i.id = o.order_id
WHERE
  i.name LIKE 'La%'
  AND c.id = 1
GROUP BY
  c.id,
  c.name,
  i.id,
  i.name
```

Comment: I was also in the middle of writing this same answer, so I second it and upvote.

Answer (score 4):

> select i.name from customers c
>   join oders o
>   on c.id = o.customer_id
>   join Items i
>   on o.id = i.order_id where c.id = WHATEVER_CUSTOMER_ID_YOU_WANT
>   and i.name LIKE 'La%'

Answer (score 1):

Sub-SELECT is one approach, another would be to JOIN the tables and query that.

Something like this, my SQL is very rusty but I think this should work.

```
SELECT c.Name, o.id, o.date, i.name, i.quantity FROM Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders AS o ON c.id = o.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items AS i on o.id = i.order_id
WHERE i.name LIKE 'La%' AND c.id = 1
```

Comment: Rusty SQL and a tendency to look for the complex answer (a habit I'm trying to break at the moment, far too long spent with complex problems). You are right, unnecessary to OUTER JOIN, even a straight JOIN would be sufficient given the limiting criteria.